# I want to upload/download images from my FTP to my Android App

Tags: android, http, ftp

I just use SimpleFTP that's a library that only can allows you to upload photos to the FTP server. The problem is that I need to download images and I need to sync image names that I insert in my database too.

So what's the best way FTP or HTTP because FTP it's faster than HTTP but I didn't find a library to download images by name. Please provide some libraries with usage or code.

Comment: Have a look at `FTPClient` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to do not use ftp. If more than one user at the same time makes upload or download request, ftp is shutting down. You must use webservices.